# Color Picker Like Sketch in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to enable a color picker like Sketch's in Illustrator? I really like the ability to drag the color slider while keeping my saturation/brightness consistent (this is just beneath the big color box in the screenshot below).  If there is an option to do this kind of adjustment in Illustrator that's great too, but I can't seem to find it. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The Color Picker in Illustrator CC already has very similar functionality. [See example](https://imgur.com/IhRZOwl). The only real difference is there is no transparency/opacity slider. Opacity has its own slider in the tool options along the top. Does this not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to implement Sketch's color picker in Illustrator.

You *can* set the **Color Panel** in Illustrator to use **HSB** - Hue, Saturation, Brightness.

[image]

This allows for adjustments to Saturation or Brightness without altering the Hue.

Unfortunately the Color Panel has a tendency to switch back to the Document Color Mode (RGB/CMYK) as you work. So, at times, it's necessary to *repeatedly* reset the panel to HSB. Users have been asking for a fix for this for some time now.

Comment: You're showing the Color Panel, not the [Color Picker dialog](https://imgur.com/IhRZOwl).

Comment: @BillyKerr And I *specifically* stated "Color **Panel**" in the answer. I have quite honestly **never** used the color *picker* in Illustrator, ever in 30+ years. It is entirely superfluous and unnecessary and poorly integrated into the AI UI.   Merely because the question states "color picker" that doesn't mean my answer *must* reference the color picker.

Comment: Oh, OK.  I just thought I'd mention it. Whatever floats your boat ;)